# System() call returns 255, but executes afterwards

Tags: c++, shell, system-calls, qnx, mongoose-web-server

I am running mongoose 3.7 server on my qnx system.

I receive http request to upgrade the firmware. On the request, I use, `system()` call in the request handler to upgrade the firmware.

But, strangely, `system()` returns 255. The same call was working before with mongoose 2.0.

Even more strange, the command which I issued through the `system()` call works after it returned 255.

I am using `WEXITSTATUS` to know the error which `system()` returns

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue..

The issue was that the mongoose call back thread which issues the system() command will not wait for the return status becuase of this line:

On the mg_start() function, which starts the server thread, they have included this line:

`mg_start()` line no 5159:

```
(void) signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

They have done this inorder to not create a zombie process.

Ref: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-5.html

But, According to QNX documentation,

> “Setting a signal action to `SIG_IGN` for a signal that's pending
>   causes the pending signal to be discarded, whether or not it is
>   blocked. If a process sets the action for the `SIGCHLD` signal to
>   `SIG_IGN`, the behavior is unspecified.”

calling `SIG_IGN` on `SIGCHLD` causes the parent process to ignore the status signal from the child.

When we make a `system()` call, it blocks the SIGCHLD signal from the shell that is being launched. According to UNIX documentation:

> “Blocking `SIGCHLD` while waiting for the child to terminate prevents
>   the application from catching the signal and obtaining status from
>   system()'s child process before `system()` can get the status itself.”

But, since mongoose discards the signal, it does not wait for the signal from `system()` at all.

It simply continues to serve the response without a valid return status from `system()`.

I just commented out this line for the time being. And it’s working.